# Copy Paste from one drive to another - permissions error

Tags: network, hard-drive, permission, copy-paste

What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to copy 1.5TB of data from a Network drive (Drive G) on a Windows 10 PC and paste it to an external drive on my Mac Mini (Sonoma 14.2.1), the external drive name is Ext-4TB.

Error:

When I attempt to copy/paste, I receive this error message: “The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items”.

What I'm after:

I would like to know how to resolve this issue. Is it a permission's problem with Drive G or External Drive "Ext-4TB"?

Comment: How are you connecting the two computers? How are you accessing the Windows box from the Mac (or vice versa)?